# Max-weight set of disjoint paths of length k in a graph G

Tags: algorithm, tree, graph-theory

Suppose you have a graph G with vertices V and edges E. The edges are weighted. You are given a number k. Find the set of paths in G where each path has exactly k edges and the sum of the weights of all edges in the set is maximized. Also, these paths must be disjoint (they can't share any vertex) In other words, I am trying to find the max weight set of disjoint paths of length k in G. Also, I can assume G is a rooted tree. I thought reversing Dijkstra's would be a good start but I don't think that actually gets me anywhere. Any advice/help?

Comment: Should I break the tree down by levels? I feel like that would be useful.

Comment: It's best to first try breaking a problem down so that subproblems have the same structure as the original problem.

Comment: Yea, so if I assume the tree is of height n, then I first start at the subtrees of at level n-k right? Because each of those subtrees will just have one max path of length k. Am I on the right track here?

Comment: I think you're trying to think about this bottom-up, but it's easier to come up with the right recursion by thinking top-down.  How does DFS in a rooted tree break down the problem of visiting every node?

Comment: Also write @j_random_hacker (or whatever username) in comments or I won't be notified.

Comment: @j_random_hacker Ok, so maybe I should start at the root and keep track of a MaxSetWeight and an actual set of the paths, lets store it in MaxSetPaths. So I call DFS at the root and find the max weight path starting at the root with k edges and store this as the MaxSetWeight. Then I move down to the next level and do it again. At each step if a path overlaps a path that already exists in MaxSetPath, I need to account for that in MaxSetWeight by subtracting the value of the path being replaced from MaxSetWeight and adding the new path into the MaxSetPath. Am I on the right track?

Comment: It's not what I'm thinking of.  I may have confused things by talking about "top-down" and "bottom-up" -- my methodology of designing the recursion is top-down, but the actual order in which subproblems wind up getting solved is bottom-up.  Here's a big hint: Suppose you already had optimal solutions for the subtrees rooted at each of the root's children.  Can you use these solutions to build an optimal solution for the entire problem?

Comment: @j_random_hacker Yea, you could run DFS at the root, find the max weighted path with k edges and if it overlaps any paths in our max set, see if replacing those paths with this new path increases our max total weight. If it does, replace the paths and return the final set, if not, just return our existing set. I see a problem with this though. What if replacing paths creates the possibility to create new paths in the subtrees with the newly opened vertices.

Comment: We *could* simply pool together the k-paths from each of the root's children, since we know they can't overlap.  But that would ignore the possibility of including some edges between the root and its children.  (Which combinations of these edges are legal to use?)  If you think about all the ways that the edges from the root to its children can be incorporated into a solution, you'll see the answer to my previous comment's question is "Not quite".

Comment: @j_random_hacker So we have to recurse where the base case is hit at the bottom but we start recursing at the top?

Comment: That's right.  (pad, pad)

Comment: I've got to do some work now, but here's a final tip: If you think about all the ways that the edges from the root to its children can be incorporated into a solution, you will realise that you could figure out the optimal way of doing so if you also had optimal solutions to a set of *other, related* problems for each of the root's children.  Of course, if you want to have the solutions to these problems available for all children of the current node, you'll need to compute them *for* the current node as well -- to provide them to *its* parent.

Comment: @j_random_hacker sorry, late response, but thanks for the help. :)